# How do you change the slide master in a slide library using Sharepoint 2007 and Powerpoint 2007?

Tags: 2007, document-library, document-template

I'm using a slide library in sharepoint 2007 in combination with powerpoint 2007. When I want to create a new presentation by using a slide that is stored in sharepoint I get a little problem.

Copy Slide to presentation->Copy to a new presentation [x]Keep the source presentation format

This function works quite well, but when I now take a deep look in my new presentation I recognize that powerpoint added a second master instead of using the one stored in sharepoint only. The bad thing is that powerpoint uses the "office theme" instead of our custom one.

I tried to change the blank slide master in powerpoint, but doing this only changes the default slide master when starting powerpoint alone not via sharepoint.

Does anybody have a solution or an idea, how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/work-with-a-slide-library-HA102080638.aspx#_Toc273516337), you can use the slide master in the target slide deck, but you must clear the option "Keep Source Formatting."

I have verified this works for me. I also see it confirmed in another office.microsoft.com [article on slide masters](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/apply-multiple-slide-masters-to-a-new-or-existing-presentation-HA010251353.aspx#BM4).